# How do I clear out an SQLite database on application exit?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite

In my application, I would like to completely clear out the contents of an SQLite database when the application quits.  How would I implement this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write this method in appdelegate file.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<your db with extention>"]] error:NULL];
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, I tried it. But problem is still there, each time I Build and Run the app, previous contents still there

Comment: First you look in your rsd file which is included in project. i think it is already populated with records. Remove all record from there.

Comment: And don't close simulator directly just press home button on it and then you can start simulator again. and you will find all data remove from database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the delete statement in sqlite in the appdelegate method, write done the code in the below method or you can use it in applicationdidenterbackground appdelegate method.

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `applicationWillTerminate`or `applicationWillEnterBackground`.

What is important to note is that, on the simulator, if your app is running, and you build and run again from Xcode, the process is just killed. It does not terminate nicely and go through your exit functions.

If you press the home button on the simulator, `applicationWillEnterBackground` is called, if you then double-click the hold button and terminate your app from the multitasking dock, `applicationWillTerminate` will be called.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the drop table either if it support in iphone or you have to delete the `yourDB.sqlite` file from the path of db.

```
NSFileManager *fMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fMgr removeItemAtPath:dbPath error:NULL];
```

this will delete your file from the app.